# I don't see any paths in the browser in my angular app

Tags: angular, typescript

What could be the reason that I don't see any paths in the browser but only localhost:4200 . But I can navigate normally through the application. My routing.ts looks like this.

I use Angular 12

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { VacComponent } from './modules/vac/vac.component';
import { VibComponent } from './modules/vib/vib.component';
import { CatComponent } from './modules/cat/cat.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login'},
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    // canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'vac',
    component: VacComponent,
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/vac/vac.module').then(m => m.VacModule),
    // canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'vib',
    component: VibComponent,
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/vib/vib.module').then(m => m.VibModule),
    // canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'cat',
    component: CatComponent,
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/cat/cat.module').then(m => m.CatModule),
    // canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried reproducing your error in a Stackblitz without success. [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hwstie?file=src/app/app-routing.module.ts) is the link. What I found strange in your example is that you don't specify a pathMatch to your first redirect. I think that might be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the Angular compiler matches routes by a prefix. Therefore the route `{ path: '', redirectTo: 'login'}` will match all the subsequent routes in the `routes` array.

Also since the default route matching strategy is set to `prefix`, which basically indicates that the Angular `Router` will route on the basis of the path that matches with the **prefix** of the URL you are navigating to. And as every path starts with '' all the redirects navigates the user to `/login` component.

Therefore, to resolve this issue you need to explicitly change the route matching strategy to `full`.

```js
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  ...,
  ...,

];
```

As `pathMatch: full` indicates that the entirety of the URL path needs to be matched for the Angular Router to route, user to the directed path.

Or,

Move the route definition with `pathMatch: prefix` to the bottom of the `routes` array as shown in the following snippet.

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  ...,
  ...,
  ...,

  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'prefix'
  }

]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. tested with pathMatch: 'full' and 'prefix'. But the problem is still there. Also tested on Firefox, Safari and Chromium.

Comment: Can you please confirm whether you are using `skipLocationChange` property in `navigate` method of class `Router` or not? Thanks.

Comment: i have seached trough my projekt and didnt found the skipLocationChange property

Comment: I am facing same issue , were you able to solve this? In my case I am able to see routes in URL in development mode , but not in prod mode